# Initializing std::list in freshly allocated memory

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to incrementally introduce C++ constructs into an existing C program to ease ongoing maintenance. An initial item is replacing linked lists with std::list to reduce code size and get access to STL iterators, etc.

The program uses malloc() to allocate memory for an array of structs, each of which contains a linked list. Simply replacing the linked-list pointer with a std::list fails because the std::list isn't initialized. Here's a simplified example, something is needed after the malloc() to initialize the lists:

```
#include <list>

typedef struct {
  float f;
  int i;
} elt;

typedef struct {
  std::list<elt> elt_list;
} elt_struct;


int main() {

  elt_struct *my_data;

  my_data = static_cast<elt_struct *>(malloc (100 * sizeof (elt_struct)));

  elt e;
  e.f = 3.14;
  e.i = 4;

  my_data[0].elt_list.push_front(e);

  e.f = 2.71;
  e.i = 8;

  my_data[0].elt_list.push_front(e);

  return (0);
}
```

Edit: Following the hint from @LogicSuff, the right answer appears to be changing the initialization of my_data to:

```
std::vector<elt_struct> my_data (100);
```

Replacing malloc() statements with modern alternatives will be an ongoing process...

Comment: Use `new`, not `malloc` in C++.

Comment: @BaumMitAugen I also considered removing the C tag, but the question seems appropriatly tagged with C and C++ for being about moving from a C parent to a C++ offspring.

Comment: Use `std::vector`, not `new[]` in C++.

Comment: @Yunnosch But the question is about C++ code, not about C code.

Comment: @Yunnosch C doesn't support list datatype.

Comment: @BaummitAugen It is about C code, which is in the process of becoming C++. See the other comments for examples.

Comment: @Yunnosch It doesn't matter if it is C code.  If they are going to compile it with a C++ compiler then it is C++, not C.

Comment: @Yunnosch Again, this question is not about C, so it should not be tagged C. It is about C++ and only C++.

Comment: @Yunnosch that crossed my mind too, but considering a C programmer without knowledge of C++ is highly unlikely to be able to answer, I'd say it's correct

Comment: The code is C++, true. But tagging is about describing what the question is about, not what code it contains.

Comment: you are going to find it hard to gradually migrate. Mixing old mallocy code with new C++y code aint going to work, without tying yourself in knots with various dark arts like custom allocators, placement news,....

Comment: @PasserBy That is a reasoning I can support. But not the "it is C++ code" one.

Comment: I would firs convert it to use new everywhere instead of malloc, keeping the data structures the same. Then change the data structrues

Comment: Calling malloc only acquires raw memory.  Casting a pointer to memory into elt_struct * does not mean that that pointer now points to an actual elt_struct, because that class requires a constructor call before the list will be initialized.  Changing to vector works because it is constructed as you declare it (instead of taking raw memory and pretending it's a vector, for example.)